# Catchable fatal error Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my PHP-Code:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

$abfrage = "SELECT `Name`, `Adresse`, `Telefon`, `Nr` FROM `tbl_test1` WHERE 1";
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, $abfrage);

?>
```

I want to show the Value of $ergebnis but it says that it could not be converted to sting. Iam a totaly beginner in PHP so please help me...

Comment: I Installed XAMPP and using a apache and a mysql database local on my computer, the sql select* option gave me the "WHERE 1" in the end dont know if its correct. But when i want to paste your code it came an error like this: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'"

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ergebnis)){ echo $row['Name']; }`  Add it between `$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, $abfrage);` and `?>`

Comment: MrAmok  please check my answer and if correct then mark it as a answer. thanks.

Comment: Why we are wasting time when people are not interested. I am deleting my answer.